# Creation of Balance Column

Tags: mysql

I've three tables, 
`t_PRODS (ID, NAME, OLD_QTY)`,
`t_INS (ID, PROVIDER_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, QTY)` and 
`t_OUTS (ID, DEPLOYER_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, QTE)`, then I join them all with UNION ALL to show them all, with two columns for the QTY, the 1st column for the QTY_IN and the other column for the QTE_OUT

```
SELECT 'Old quantity' AS OPERATION, ID, OLD_QTY AS Q_IN, NULL AS Q_OUT FROM t_PRODS
UNION ALL
SELECT PROVIDER_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, QTY, NULL FROM t_INS
UNION ALL
SELECT DEPLOYER_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, NULL, QTY FROM t_OUTS
```

My problem here is that I want to display another column of balance like this :

```
OPERATION        ID    Q_IN     Q_OUT     **BALANCE**
Old quantity     1     2        NULL      2
PROVIDER_1       1     20       NULL      22
PROVIDER_2       3     6        NULL      28
DEPLOYER_1       1     NULL     3         25
DEPLOYER_1       1     NULL     6         19
PROVIDER_2       4     5        NULL      24
PROVIDER_3       2     6        NULL      30
DEPLOYER_2       2     NULL     12        18
DEPLOYER_3       4     NULL     7         11
```

Really i can't resolve this, any help will be appreciated !

Comment: How the balance is calculated ?

Comment: **BALANCE** (of current record) = **BALANCE** (of previous record) + **Q_IN** (of current record) - **Q_OUT** (of current record)

Comment: How can a field that doesn't exist be used to calculate the field of the current record?

Comment: As @BenM said, how can we calculate the line `Old quantity     1     2        NULL      2`

Comment: `SET @rank:= 0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rowid`
This is an example of creating such thing @BenM
I don't say that BALANCE is a physical table field, it is just calculated in a SELECT statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i solved it !!!

```
SET @BALANCE:= 0;
SELECT A.*, @balance:=@balance + IFNULL(A.Q_IN, 0) - IFNULL(A.Q_OUT, 0)
from
(
(SELECT 'Old quantity' AS OPERATION, ID, OLD_QTY AS Q_IN, NULL AS Q_OUT FROM t_PRODS)
union all
(SELECT PROVIDER_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, QTY, NULL FROM t_INS)
union all
(SELECT 'Old quantity' AS OPERATION, ID, OLD_QTY AS Q_IN, NULL AS Q_OUT FROM t_PRODS)
) AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Old quantity' AS OPERATION, ID, OLD_QTY AS Q_IN, NULL AS Q_OUT, BALACNE = 'BALANCE (of previous record) + Q_IN (of current record) - Q_OUT (of current record)' FROM t_PRODS
UNION ALL
SELECT PROVIDER_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, QTY, NULL, NULL FROM t_INS
UNION ALL
SELECT DEPLOYER_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, NULL,NULL, QTY FROM t_OUTS
```

**Note : Make sure you replace `'BALANCE (of previous record) + Q_IN (of current record) - Q_OUT (of current record)'` by the columns from which the values are taken to calculate Balance**